# How to write triangle probability functions in R

Tags: r, function, statistics, probability

I am trying to build different (triangle) probability functions in R. For example:

```r
#' the density function
#' @param `x` - (double) values where one evaluates the density
#' @param `a` - (double) the minimum value of distribution
#' @param `b` - (double >a) the maximum value of the distribution
#' @param `c` - (double [a,b]) the position of the largest density value
#' @param `log` - (logical) if true compute the logarithm of the density.
#' @return the density at x
```

But I do not know where to start, and I find no information online. Any suggestions?

I have tried different approaches, but I cannot solve it.

Comment: #' the density function

#' @param `x` - (double) values where one evaluates the density

#' @param `a` - (double) the minimum value of distribution

#' @param `b` - (double >a) the maximum value of the distribution

#' @param `c` - (double [a,b]) the position of the largest density value

#' @param `log` - (logical) if true compute the logarithm of the density.

#' @return the density at x

Comment: Some help on formatting questions: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189. I suggested an edit to make it easier to read, I'm assuming your comment was hoping to clarify that.

Comment: Many times (but not all) I see people implement new (whether innovative or not) distribution functions, they are based internally on the Uniform distribution with some numerical transformation internally. I suspect you can do that here as well. You can see one such implementation here: https://github.com/bertcarnell/triangle